# Optionally generate output with an Azure Function

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs, azure-functions

I currently have a Timer triggered Azure Function that checks a data endpoint to determine if any new data has been added. If new data has been added, then I generate an output blob (which I return).

However, returning output appears to be mandatory. Whereas I'd only like to generate an output blob under specific conditions, I must do it all of the time, clogging up my storage.

Is there any way to generate output only under specified conditions?

Comment: Can't you simply return `null` if you don't want to generate a blob?

Comment: Returning `null` seems to be the simplest solution @AndrésNava-.NET

Answer (score 11):

If you have the blob output binding set to your return value, but you do not want to generate a blob, simply return null to ensure the blob is not created.

Comment: I have also tested this with a queue output type and returning null works for that output method as well.

Answer (score 2):

You're free to execute whatever logic you want in your functions. You may need to remove the output binding from your function (this is what is making the output required) and construct the connection to blob storage in your function instead. Then you can conditionally create and save the blob.

Comment: That comes with extra burden though, so it's easier to stick to bindings

Comment: @Mikhail Sometimes that's true. I've also encountered a decent number of scenarios where it's nicer to just deal with a client itself instead of relying on bindings. Ie CosmosDb bindings returning null to your function when the DB is being throttled instead of passing the exception forward.... Not nice